# How does spring boot find the path url very fast

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, path, annotations

I just started learning spring boot and learned about rest services.
I have a doubt that how spring is so fast to find that exact path('') class file in multiple jars.
Like I am sure it does not traverse the whole codebase. So does it maintain an index file with every URL and class file name?

Example: Below is given index function which is present in TestController.java file which should be called when /index is called. But if I have multiple jars in my project how the Spring knows that a getMapping of Greetings is defined in that class.

```
package com.example.springboot;

 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
 @RestController
 public class HelloController {

@GetMapping("/Greetings")
public String index() {
    return "Greetings from Spring Boot!";
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

when you start spring boot application it scans for the classes which are annotated with stereotype annotation like @Controller, @Restcontroller,@Bean,@service.

when a class is annotated with @Controller  it means it handles web requests. After the component scan it creates a bean for that class and stores it in spring Ioc container.

when a web request is made to the server it looks for the requested url is presented in that bean and serves the request.

A Bean is a simple object of that class.